# How can i include another file in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have many typescript file a.ts, and another typescript file b.ts. how can i inlcude a.ts into b.ts? so when compile b.ts to javascript b.js, the content from a.ts is attached to b.js automatically. I know, in LESS we can use import "a.less' inside b.less, so when compiled to b.css, the content of a.css is automatically included in b.css. Does typescript have similar syntax?

Comment: TypeScript uses modules and ES6 style `import` statements - consult the official documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: You can also use [triple-slashes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) depending on what you're doing. But it's not a recommended technique. JavaScript (and TypeScript) rely on modules instead like UnholySheep mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does typescript have similar syntax?

You *can* use `outFile` and if `a.ts` and `b.ts` are in your [compilation context](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/content/docs/project/compilation-context.html).

But instead I highly recommend you use modules : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

And then compile using webpack : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html